# Are data that can be obtained from the text of a report considered to be in the public domain?

Tags: copyright, data

I have been working with some data from a technical report that is freely available online as a PDF document from the website of the institution that published the report.  I've cut and pasted the data from tables in the report for my research (and written a program to process it as the data are stored in an odd order in the PDF tables).  I'd quite like to use this data as a part of a machine learning benchmark (with proper attribution, of course).  Would the data be considered as being in the public domain and available for use for academic purposes, and made available in a more machine readable format?

I should add, I will of course be asking permission to distribute the data, I was just interested in the expectations surrounding this; is it a courtesy (as it is in the public domain) or is it a substantial favour that is being asked (or somewhere in the middle)?

Comment: Did you try to find a license under which the data/technical report is published? If there is any, it should be possible to find it somewhere on the website.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the Coca-Cola logo just because it is easy to find?

Comment: It it is question of law vs of academic etiquette and norms I would ask on Law SE. Copyright law is not straightforward. For example, plain facts are not subject to copyright but arrangements of facts might be.

Comment: @EarlGrey I don't think that is quite analogous, the purpose of scientific/technical reports is to let other researchers know what you have done so that they can build on it.   The report could just describe what was done and leave it at that, but *all* of the data is given in tables, in full.  Quite a lot of statistics benchmark problems are taken from data given in old papers.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I am mostly interested in what the expectations would be, for the author of the report as well as the researchers.

Comment: @Snijderfrey There doesn't seem to be any licence or statement of copyright (it is written in German).

Comment: @EarlGrey A trademarked logo is subject to trademark and copyright law; data is not subject to either (at least in the USA).

Comment: Copyright notice is no longer required.  Ask on Law SE for legal issues. Here for plagiarism, professional etiquette etc and academic norms.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial "There doesn't seem to be any licence or statement of copyright (it is written in German)." Huge assumption from your side, then. You did not find one, it does not mean that there isn't one. Since you downloaded it from the institution page, either there was a notice there or you ask directly the institution.
Assumptions are like plutonium: they decay with time, use cautiosly and in small doses, if you don't know them you are bound to get burned.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist really? for example here:
https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/XRCu-SyFrrG2mKj1zF8ohJ_pniwGJcDOsrMWgHpppWvyxGIk98SGz3KGgVFcdQ4WrQ=w240-h480-rw
"there doesn't seem to be any licence or statement of copyright"

Comment: @EarlGray "Huge assumption from your side, then." I wish people wouldn't put words into my mouth that I have not said.  I have made no assumption of anything - I am asking questions.

Comment: @EarlGray if there is some subtext in your response to AnonymousPhysicist underlying the quote from my comment, I don't know what it is.  I looks like a snark, but I will assume it is not.

Comment: @downvoter, would be interested to know the reason why.  In statistics a lot of benchmark datasets are taken from tables in papers.  The expectations on usage are not all that clear, hence the question.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial - I'm not the downvoter, but I'd guess that it's for the implied assumption that if you weren't _allowed_ to use the data then you wouldn't be _able_ to do so.  Whether the data can be copy/pasted or would have to be transcribed by hand has no effect on whether you're allowed to do it or not.  I think the question itself is fine, but you may want to revise the title to remove the copy/paste reference.

Comment: @Bobson thanks for the useful feedback, I've made the suggested edit.  I suspect the version of the dataset I first used several decades ago may well have been typed in manually from a printed version of an earlier report.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question asks about "public domain" but these are really the wrong words to use, as a) it's complicated but unlikely that these data are public domain, and b) it might not matter much for what you are asking to do.

If you just want to *use* the data, I don't know of any law that would make this illegal, even if the data could be considered a copyrightable database (that is, data are not copyrightable, but collections of data can be). Academic convention is of course to cite, and if the primary data in your paper are from some other source you'll end up going quite a bit beyond just a simple citation and likely have to describe specifically where and why you got the data from that source.

If you want to also *distribute* the data, rather than just your analysis of the data, that's where you could possibly get into trouble if they were indeed deemed a copyrightable collection (which, of course, they might not), were not associated with a license that allowed you to distribute in the manner you would like to distribute, and it would be safest to just get permission. However, you probably do not need to post the data at all if they are freely available, just point others to where they can be found.

This is a good reminder that if you do produce and distribute data you would like others to be able to use to remember that you should include a license with those data to avoid any ambiguity as to whether people can use the data; if there is no license given, it must be assumed that the authors reserve all rights allowed to them. If your preference is that others use your work, let them know by using a license! Note also that even for data that *are* released as public domain or with a similarly permissive license, academic standards of citation still apply; licenses give you legal rights only, not ethical ones.

Answer (score 8):

Taking your question literally:  In the United States, data is not subject to copyright.  Some sources state that only creative works can be in the "public domain."  If you use that interpretation, then data is not in the public domain.

Example references:
https://sco.library.emory.edu/research-data-management/publishing/copyright-data.html
https://guides.uflib.ufl.edu/copyright/datamanagement

Comment: I think this answer could use a little bit more nuance for a couple reasons. While it's true that "facts" (i.e., data) can't be copyrighted, data "compilations" or data "curations" can be: https://blogs.libraries.indiana.edu/scholcomm/2017/12/12/copyright-and-data-curation/ Personally, the point where something becomes a data compilation is clear as mud to me. Tables of raw data should be fine, but redistributing a database might not be

Comment: The other thing is that while tables of raw data should not be restricted by copyright law, tables with "data" that is derived from some other source might actually be covered by copyright; depends on if the authors of said derived data can reasonably make an argument that their process has creative originality. But if was a clearly banal process, then it should be fine. Again, I'm not going to claim the boundary between the two is always clear

Comment: @anjama: Collections of data are only protectable to the extent that they fall within the requirements [set by the Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_Publications,_Inc.,_v._Rural_Telephone_Service_Co.) (under US law, other countries differ). In short: It has to have some degree of originality (creativity) in the "selection or arrangement" of the data, or in the accompanying text and presentational elements (if any). But the underlying facts themselves cannot be subject to protection in the US.

Comment: @anjama What you say is true, but it's not what the question asks about.

Answer (score 2):

Without a license or a clear statement that it is in the public domain you must assume that the creators hold all rights. In most jurisdictions these days copyright is automatic. It need not be asserted, though it is helpful to do so.

You should ask the creators for permission (a license) for any use beyond fair use. Using "all" of it is likely not fair use.

But no, you can't assume that the things you find online are public domain.

You may be able to "use" the data for another analysis, but probably not able, ethically, to republish it in any form without permission.

---

Note that I've assumed that some level of "creativity" was involved in producing the data.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138892/discussion-on-answer-by-buffy-are-data-that-can-be-obtained-from-the-text-of-a-r).